# Modal draw operator repeat draw function 8 times on every action

Tags: python, operator

Need advice. Is it intendant behavior? In this simple example every action in blender modal operator prints me 8 time "Hello!" (in complex it calculates coordinates and draw some shape in a view). So every single action it calculates 8 time the same result. Is it possible to regulate how many times it draw for every single action?

```
import bpy


def draw_callback_px(context):
    print("Hello!")


class ModalDrawOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Draw a line with the mouse"""
    bl_idname = "view3d.modal_draw_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Modal View3D Operator"

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type == 'ESC':
            bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(self._handle, 'WINDOW')
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        self._handle = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw_callback_px, (context, ), 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
    

def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(ModalDrawOperator.bl_idname, text="Modal Draw Operator")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalDrawOperator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_view.append(menu_func)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalDrawOperator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_view.remove(menu_func)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: You can save the time it last executed in a variable and return early from the function if the current time - that time is less than a certain amount

Comment: It is the intendant behavior, why are you trying to control it?

Comment: All about performance. Modal operator assigned to bool checkbox and executes nonstop until bool off. Like draw edge length but more expensive calculation. I used similar to Gorgious example. So it's ok now.